# make jQuery load only once in joomla

Tags: jquery, joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla-module

I'm creating a module for joomla that needs jQuery and some jQuery plugins.
My problem is that if other plugins load jQuery too it rewrites mine and disables jQuery plugins!
How can I make sure jQuery loads only once (And before my plugins) in page?
thanks.

Comment: Did we answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

dont load jquery each time, test first if it's already loaded

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined') {
            document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The information provided here will probably solve your issues:

[Load JQuery only once](http://old.nabble.com/Load-JQuery-only-once-td20612946s27240.html)